# Exporting Access data to Excel data source contains no visible tables

Tags: excel, ms-access

I'm trying to export several Access queries to Excel using the in-built 'get data from Access' function. The first table was im-/ex-ported fine, but after that it keeps showing the message 'Data source contains no visible tables' and wouldn't get the data in. Anyone knows why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From within Excel 2010, link to the Access 2010 tables or queries via Microsoft Query (from the other data sources menu in Excel).
This method, rather than trying to link using "From Access", gives you a view of the tables whether linked to a backend db or not and also to queries in the Access file.

Comment: Also try renaming your files. No periods, spaces or the sort. Keep the necessary files in the same folder. And make sure no 2 files have the same name (eg xyz.xlsx and xyz.db is a no-no)